# Xcode document based windows do not free resources when closed

Tags: xcode, cocoa, memory-leaks

When creating Document based applications I notice that the memory allocation is not reduced when windows are closed - regardless of whether ARC is enabled. To demonstrate, simply create a generic document based application with Xcode. Then choose Product/Profile and select the leaks... When your application stats open a few new windows - as one would expect the memory allocation increases for each new window. However, if you close the window these resources are not released. The profiler does not tag these as leaks - I assume that the windows still have active resources, but effectively as the user opens and closes windows the memory will be consumed (much more rapidly for real world applications where each window has additional objects associated with it. My question is - will an Xcode application eventually release this memory pool, or are these orphaned closed windows always going to retain memory? Is this a problem, or not?

I have seen similar questions for non-document based applications where the user creates their own window controller.... but I am not sure whether the comments are relevant or elegant for the document based model
 http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/119250-nswindowcontroller-with-nsobjectcontroller-doesn-dealloc.html

As well as this page
 http://theocacao.com/document.page/18